# Getting error E1216 while trying to run minishift on windows machine

Tags: docker, openshift, minishift

I am trying to run minishift using VirtualBox in my windows 10 machine but I am getting an error. I have already enabled Virtualization and have some versions of Ubuntu up and running on VirtualBox. Can you please tell me what is the problem?

```
C:\minishift-1.34.3-windows-amd64>minishift start
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    4 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 20 GB
-- Starting Minishift VM ..... FAIL E1216 17:01:47.771710   13044 start.go:499] Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory". Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```